# ListBox: Display multiple selected items?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, listbox, selecteditem

When I select multiple items in a `ListBox`, how can I display them? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where you want to display those selected items?

Comment: Mabe you should explain the problem a littlbit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to set the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) property on your `ListBox` to either [`SelectionMode.MultiSimple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode.aspx) or [`SelectionMode.MultiExtended`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode.aspx) (so that you *can* select multiple items).

Next, you need to add an event handler for the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event on your `ListBox`. Within this event handler, accessing the [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) collection of your `ListBox` will provide you with access to a collection of all the selected objects.

From there, you can iterate through the collection to display the objects in any manner you choose. Here's an example event handler that displays the selected items in a `TextBox` called `textBox1`:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Clear();
   foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
   {
      textBox1.AppendText(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
   }
}
```